# Keep slider in usercontrol from scaling in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, touch, scaling

I have a user control which contains a media element to play a video, a slider used as a trackbar for the video and a text block that display the title of the video. These 3 controls are placed in a grid which in turn is placed inside a border.

I want the user to be able to translate, rotate and scale this control. The problem is that when the control scales it's content scales also and i want the slider control not to scale. Is it possible to somehow keep the slider control from scaling?

I should also mention that the manipulation of the control is handled by setting the control ismanipulationenabled to true and using the manipulation delta event.

EDIT:

This is how the xaml for the control looks like:

```
    <Grid Name="movieGrid" ShowGridLines="True">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border x:Name="moviePlayerBorder" Background="Black" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="2,2,2,2" CornerRadius="5,5,5,5"  Grid.RowSpan="2">

                <Grid Name="contentGrid">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <WinControls:MediaElement x:Name="movieDisplay" ScrubbingEnabled="True" IsEnabled="True" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                      LoadedBehavior="Manual" UnloadedBehavior="Manual" 
                                      MediaOpened="movieDisplay_MediaOpened">
            </WinControls:MediaElement>


        <Image x:Name="btnPlay" Grid.Row="1" Height="60" Width="60" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="120,44,112,43" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                </Image>

                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="6,2,6,0" Grid.Row="0">
                        <TextBlock Text="test" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="txtBlockTitlu" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                   FontSize="14" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Border>



        <Slider x:Name="seekBar" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="299"
                         Thumb.DragStarted="seekBar_DragStarted" Thumb.DragCompleted="seekBar_DragCompleted" Thumb.DragDelta="seekBar_DragDelta" MaxHeight="33" 

                         Minimum="0" Maximum="286" Height="33" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Have you set a Max height and width to the slider?

Comment: @Redburn Yes i've tried that but it didn't work

Comment: Is it possible to post some code?

Comment: @Redburn I've edited my question and added the xaml for the user control.

Comment: I believe the error has to be in the control manipulation code. Recreating the form (besides of course the drag and resize code) the slider worked as expected, not resizing the slider when resizing the window. The only change I made was removing the WinControls prefix to the MediaElement control. Sorry I could not spot anything for you.

Comment: @Redburn Well from what I've read on the web when you scaletransform a usercontrol all of its content is scaled also. Is there something i could do to go around this behaviour?

Comment: I see your issue now. The only thing I can think is doing some custom code in your delta/drag events that will transform everything expect that control.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to build a fully scaleable user control you should define the layout only with the size values of a row column / row row eg. auto, x* or fixed values (if realy needed).

do not use fixed size values on elements.

Comment: I'm not interested in scaling the slider. I want to keep it from scaling when the user control scales.